# Access to index of list field in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

models.py

```
class Keys(models.Model):
    CHOICES     = (('a','a'),('b','b'),('c','c'),('d','d'))
    choice           =   MultiSelectField(choices=CHOICES,blank=True)
```

My template:

```
{% for k in m.choice %}
  {{????}}
{% endfor %}
```

How i can access to index of value in list fields?
If user was selected a and c, Sample Output:

```
0
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `{{ forloop.counter }}`  which is counting the loop that you are in, starting from 1 to xx.

Comment: I changed my question and output